# Работа с таблицей DataGridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Подскажите. На форме есть Datagridview, в ней к примеру 7 столбцов и неограниченное кол-во строк. Мне нужно каждый раз получать Число из ячейки которая находится в последней строке 3 столбца, и из ячейки последней строки 4 столбца, чтобы их Сложить, а потом вывести итог в ячейку Последней строки 5 столбца.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
            int value3 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[3].Value); //3 столбец 
            int value4 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[4].Value);//4 столбец
            int value5 = value3 + value4;
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[5].Value = value5; //5 столбец
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public BindingList<MyClass> Test { get; } = new BindingList<MyClass>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Test.Add(new MyClass() { a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1, e = 1 });
    Test.Add(new MyClass() { a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1 });

    dataGridView1.DataSource = Test;


    var lastRow = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2];

    var cells = lastRow.Cells;

    cells[4].Value = int.Parse(cells[2].Value.ToString()) + int.Parse(cells[3].Value.ToString());

}

public class MyClass
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public int? d { get; set; }
    public int? e { get; set; }
}
```

Вот небольшой пример